# Serial byte stream shifts array elements (Processing & Arduino)

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

I am using [Processing](http://processing.org/) to send an array of bytes to an Arduino card via a serial port. I have a strange problem where the Arduino doesn't seem to read the array "in sync" - the byte elements appear shifted to the Arduino code.

For example, from Processing I send array:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

and the Arduino could read it as:

```
array = [2, 3, 4, 0, 1];
```

This problem appears at random - about 1/3 times I try, and the shift is always random as well. When it works it continues to work for the duration of the session, until i restart the connection.

Have anyone else encountered similar problems? Do you have any suggestions as of how to fix this problem?

Regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide a code sample showing how you send and read bytes? 
Especially reading by arduino code is important.

It's not clear how you synchronize the transmission: assuming you send 5 bytes - how does the Arduino code detect when it receives a complete array? 
If you rely on a serial port buffer and just count to 5 incoming bytes assuming they make up an array examine what happens if at least once there was a byte missing (e.g. due to Processing code restart while some bytes were already sent to the Arduino).

Comment: Well this is where I guess my knowledge is lacking - I didn't understand I needed to sync them "manually". I do use a serial buffer and basically count to five. I will try to implement some sort of start byte to indicate the start of the array and get back to you if this does not solve my issue.

Comment: If you send arrays in some deterministic way (e.g. once a second or with some other interval) you may leave counting to five on the receiving side provided you add some timeout and clear the input buffer if this timeout passed. Even better is to use timeout + CRC (this is what I would recommend) but since timeout would be needed anyway you may start just with it.

Comment: This issue was eventually resolved by adding a '#' as an identifier at the start of the array. Thanks for your input!